# Distinct and DateTime in c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, xamarin

I have 2 problems. I'm trying to make my first application in xamarin, and i have list of Dates. First problem  is format. When i add bind `datetime` to label it looks like this "25.11.2021 00:00". What i can do to have only date? second problem i have with distinct. A lot of the dates are the same and I want only one unique. I can't use `DistincBy`, so i write something like this `MyList.Select(x => x.dateTime).Distinct().ToList()` but that not work. Someone can tell me what I do wrong?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  for starters: provide more detail about the trouble you're having ("does not work" is **not** a valid error description), and how you tried to solve it - and only one question per question.

Comment: Try to use the property `.Date` of DateTimes values, it will give you only the date. 

Try it also in your `.Select()` because it will check if dates are the same and not datetime, which contains precise data allowing to have tiny differences between 2 dates. 

The code for the `.Select()` would be : `MyList.Select(x => x.dateTime.Date).Distinct().ToList()`

Comment: I tried it  before, but this gives me  "25.11.2021 00:00", when i dont use it i have the same but with real time : "25.11.2021 04.40"

Comment: I see, then try to define the variable you're using as label as a `string` and use `.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")` behind your DateTime variable, this will output a string with only the date that you can display in your label. Exemple : `string myDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");`

Comment: DateTime formating and LINQ queries are both core features of C#/.NET and don't have any dependence on Xamarin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Date part

Use the `.Date` of DateTimes values, it will give you only the Date. Another better solution is to use the function `.ToString(string format)` to extract the date in a string that you will be able to use in your label. ([documentation about date format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-6.0#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_))

Exemple code :

```cs
string myDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

### Distinct part

For the `.Select()` problem, also use the `.Date` in your filter because it will check if dates are the same and not datetime, which contains precise data allowing to have tiny differences between 2 dates.

The code for the `.Select()` would be :

```cs
MyList.Select(x => x.dateTime.Date).Distinct().ToList();
```